# Is there any built in function to check whether given two numbers are in the same order in a given integer array?

Tags: c++

I want to check whether given two integers in a specific order are in the same order in a given integer array.
I wonder whether there is an easy way to do this like a built-in CPP method.
If there is no built-in method, suggest me an efficient way to do this as I have a few sets of two integers (not only one set) to check over one array.

given two numbers: 8 3
given array: 2 8 6 1 3 9
output: YES

Comment: Find first of the first number and find last of the second number. Check if first index is smaller than second.

Comment: You can use two `std::find` calls to do this. For more information on how to use the C++ library's algorithms, including `std::find`, you should find plenty of information and examples in your C++ book.

Comment: Can the array contain duplicates?

Comment: No standard CPP function comes to mind, but there may be some combination of them that works.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like

```
bool check(std::pair<int, int> numbers = {8, 3},
std::array<int, 6> arr = {2, 8, 6, 1, 3, 9}) {
    if (numbers.first != numbers.second)
        return std::find(std::find(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), numbers.first), std::end(arr), numbers.second) == std::end(arr);
    return std::count(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), numbers.first) >= 2;
}
```

If both numbers are different the inner `find` searches for the first value. The outer `find` starts at the position of the first value and searches for the second value.

Else the count is checked.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```cpp
    std::array<int, 6> content = {2, 3, 6, 1, 8, 9};
    auto lookup = [content](int a, int b)
    {
        return std::distance(std::find(content.begin(), content.end(), a), std::find(content.rbegin(), content.rend(), b));
    };
    lookup(8, 3);
```

`lookup` will be positive if 8 comes before 3 and negative otherwise.

Comment: That's what I described in the comments but I didn't know how to implement it. I didn't know that normal iterators and reverse iterators could be compared like this.

Answer (score 0):

Search the entire container to find the first one. Search from the position of the first one to the end of the container to find the second one. If that search succeeds, they're in the expected order. If not, they're not.

```
int first_value = 8;
int second_value = 3;
std::array<int, 6> values = { 2, 8, 6, 1, 3, 9 };

auto first_pos = std::find(values.begin(), values.end(), first_value);
if (first_pos != values.end())
    ++first_pos;
auto second_pos = std::find(first_pos, values.end(), second_value);
if (second_pos != values.end())
    std::cout << "YES\n";
```

Comment: I had the same idea but it gives a wrong result for `first_value = 8;
second_value = 8;`

Answer (score -1):

Use [adjacent find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find). I suppose [find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) could also do the job.

Comment: How would you use `adjacent_find` to do this?

Comment: Oops my mistake, he is not looking for consecutive elements. Only find_if or handwritten algorithm then.